# Create a multidimensional array from regular array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I am using simple html dom to get the contents of a table:

```
foreach($html->find('#maintable .table tr td') as $a) {
     $array[] = $a->plaintext;
}

print_r($array);
```

The array returned looks like this:

```
Array ( 
    [0] => 1 
    [1] => 0xd35a2d8c651f3eba4f0a044db961b5b0ccf68a2d
    [2] => 309953166.54621424
    [3] => 30.9953%
    [4] => 2
    [5] => 0xe17c20292b2f1b0ff887dc32a73c259fae25f03b
    [6] => 200000001
    [7] => 20.0000%
    [8] => 3
    [9] => 0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000
    [10] => 129336426
    [11] => 12.9336%
)
```

I would like to create a new multidimensional array from the array above that skips one row every three rows starting with the first row like this:

```
New Array (

[1]
    ['address'] => 0xd35a2d8c651f3eba4f0a044db961b5b0ccf68a2d
    ['amount'] => 309953166.54621424
    ['percent'] => 30.9953%
[2]
    ['address'] => 0xe17c20292b2f1b0ff887dc32a73c259fae25f03b
    ['amount'] => 200000001
    ['percent'] => 20.0000%
[3] 
    ['address'] => 0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000
    ['amount'] => 129336426
    ['percent'] => 12.9336%
```

)

In the new array, "address" represents [1] [5] and [9] from the original array. "amount" represents [2] [6] and [10], and "percent" represents [3] [7] and [11].

How can I accomplish this? Thank you

Comment: I believe you have accepted the wrong answer. Both the other answers are much faster as it's producing the array "on the fly", instead of first creating the array and then manipulating it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `array_chunk` to chunk the array. Use `array_reduce` to loop thru the chuncked array. Use `array_combine` to use the `$keys` array as the key.

```
$array = //Your array
$keys = array( 'address', 'amount', 'percent' );
$result = array_reduce( array_chunk( $array, 4 ), function($c, $o) use ($keys) {
    $c[ array_shift($o) ] = array_combine( $keys, $o );
    return $c;
}, array() );

echo "<pre>";
print_r( $result );
echo "</pre>";
```

This will result to:

```
Array
(
    [1] => Array
        (
            [address] => 0xd35a2d8c651f3eba4f0a044db961b5b0ccf68a2d
            [amount] => 309953166.54621424
            [percent] => 30.9953%
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [address] => 0xe17c20292b2f1b0ff887dc32a73c259fae25f03b
            [amount] => 200000001
            [percent] => 20.0000%
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [address] => 0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000
            [amount] => 129336426
            [percent] => 12.9336%
        )

)
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your array is based on 4 different elements as in in your code

```
foreach($html->find('#maintable .table tr td') as $a) {
     $array[] = $a->plaintext;
}
```

in the same relative position you could use a for loop

```
for ($i =0; $i<(count($array)/4) ; $i++){
  $myNewArra[$i]['address'] = $array[($i*4+1)];
  $myNewArra[$i]['amount'] = $array[($i*4+2)];
  $myNewArra[$i]['percent'] = $array[($i*4+3)];

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Given the input array in your example this should do what you have asked:

```
$newArray = [];
for($i=1; $i<count($oldArray); $i=($i+4)){
    $newArray[] = [
        'address'   => (isset($oldArray[$i]))     ? $oldArray[$i] : '',
        'amount'    => (isset($oldArray[($i+1)])) ? $oldArray[($i+1)] : '',
        'percent'   => (isset($oldArray[($i+2)])) ? $oldArray[($i+2)] : '',
    ];
}

print_r($newArray);
```

Producing:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [address] => 0xd35a2d8c651f3eba4f0a044db961b5b0ccf68a2d
            [amount] => 309953166.54621424
            [percent] => 30.9953%
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [address] => 0xe17c20292b2f1b0ff887dc32a73c259fae25f03b
            [amount] => 200000001
            [percent] => 20.0000%
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [address] => 0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000
            [amount] => 129336426
            [percent] => 12.9336%
        )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option might be to use the [modulo](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.arithmetic.php) `%` operator.

```
$innerKeys = ["address", "amount", "percent"];
$result = [];

for ($i = 0; $i < count($array); $i++) {
    $rem = $i % 4;
    if ($rem === 0) $outerKey = $array[$i];
    if ($rem > 0) $result[$outerKey][$innerKeys[$rem - 1]] = $array[$i];
}
print_r($result);
```

Result:

```
Array
(
    [1] => Array
        (
            [address] => 0xd35a2d8c651f3eba4f0a044db961b5b0ccf68a2d
            [amount] => 309953166.54621424
            [percent] => 30.9953%
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [address] => 0xe17c20292b2f1b0ff887dc32a73c259fae25f03b
            [amount] => 200000001
            [percent] => 20.0000%
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [address] => 0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000
            [amount] => 129336426
            [percent] => 12.9336%
        )

)
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/YktZ1)